# Web application error handling and print results

Tags: php, error-handling

Ok, i have a web app and i have split my files into pages-scripts for better management. 
For example addplayerP.php is the page with the form etc and addplayer.php is like the script page that runs all the requests queries.

What i want to do now is create an error management system. Since i don't wanna overload the script pages with headers css and html to print out the error i thought of simply returning back at the page a `$_GET['errorNo']` code and according to that the page then would print the corresponding error message.

Now what would be the best way to approach this mostly on the part of error-checking.
I mean ok i return the 1001 error but should i go with a more object oriented way (not that experienced with classes but willing to play around).

Any ideas would be appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you should be using javascript for the purposes of error handling, rather than echoing php strings.

Since, I assume, the errors you are referring to are the errors from the form filling, I suggest you get familiar with jquery, and the `submit()` function.

You should be checking stuff on the client side before you even send them to your server.

Of course, you should still be double checking it on the server side, to deal with hack attempts, but the error handling should stick to the javascript.

A quick example:

HTML:

```
<form id = "test" action = "addplayer" method = "post">
    <input type = "text" name = "name">
</form>
```

Javascript (Jquery):

```
$('#test').submit(function(){
    if ( $('#test[name="name"]').val() == "") // if its empty
    {
        alert("name cannot be empty");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
});
```

If you are familier with ajax, this should make you life so much easier:
[Ajax Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Comment: I totally agree with you on that part but in some cases the "error" might be something like "e-mail already exists" or something similar to that. I'm interested more on that part rather than validating the data submited. Thanks for the input though

Comment: You can use ajax for email validation.
Once you go ajax you can't go back, trust me.

Comment: I could also solve that with AJAX and run the check before sending the data but i don't think that would be a good idea

Comment: haha i feel you, it just i kinda overused AJAX for a while on cases i didn't needed and now i'm kinda...if i must only

Comment: It is an excellent idea! It's more user friendly, and submitting is another request anyway, so why not?

Comment: How about the "speed" side of it?

Comment: Faster than loading the page entirely.

If you want help with syntax, just let me know, or google it.

Comment: As i said before i kind of abused it early on so i'm good on it. Thank you for your help